# Android: Getting white screen in game screen

Tags: android, performance

Getting white screen in game screen in only samsung glaxy grand.Its coming proper in other only in one mobile,getting problem.can anyone help me to solve.
code used:

```
AnswersDownBtnImage.addListener(new InputListener() {
    public boolean touchDown (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
        playSound(buttonClickSound);

        if (inventorySelectObj1 == KeySofaToCashCounterImage) {
            // HintHndlr();
            Table1.removeActor(InventorySofaKeyHintImage);
            HintPanel.removeActor(Table1);
            Table1.addActor(InventoryAnswersSofaKeyImage);
            HintPanel.addActor(Table1);
            SaveData("KeySofaToCashCounterImage", "used");
        } else if (inventorySelectObj1 == WeighingkeyImage) {
            Table2.removeActor(InventoryWeighingScaleHintImage);
            Table2.addActor(InventoryAnswersWeighingscaleKeyImage);
            HintPanel.addActor(Table2);
        } else if (inventorySelectObj1 == AxeImage) {
            Table3.removeActor(InventoryAxeHintImage);
            Table3.addActor(InventoryAnswersAxeImage);
            HintPanel.addActor(Table3);
        }
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Found that some slow processing mobile has problem on loading more number of images.So i used a libgdx-texture packer  (https://code.google.com/p/libgdx-texturepacker-gui/) which resolves my problem by reducing number of images.